TypeScript Async/Await Bad Javascript Translation
I'm brand new to TypeScript and I've nearly blown a fuse trying to figure this out. I've got the following .ts code:
import * as fs from "fs";

import type { Trophy } from "psn-api";
import {
  exchangeCodeForAccessToken,
  exchangeNpssoForCode,
  getTitleTrophies,
  getUserTitles,
  getUserTrophiesEarnedForTitle,
  makeUniversalSearch,
  TrophyRarity
} from "psn-api";

async function main() {
  // 1. Authenticate and become authorized with PSN.
  // See the Authenticating Manually docs for how to get your NPSSO.
  const accessCode = await exchangeNpssoForCode("GqO4rje8Hx1sFqeEbzckLYND101S51LqWaXIrlMbC7TWybbZAYZygCqCSE8wx64E");
  const authorization = await exchangeCodeForAccessToken(accessCode);

  // 2. Get the user's `accountId` from the username.
  const allAccountsSearchResults = await makeUniversalSearch(
    authorization,
    "andykasen13",
    "SocialAllAccounts"
  );

  const targetAccountId =
    allAccountsSearchResults.domainResponses[0].results[0].socialMetadata
      .accountId;

  // 3. Get the user's list of titles (games).
  const { trophyTitles } = await getUserTitles(authorization, targetAccountId);

  const games: any[] = [];
  for (const title of trophyTitles) {
    // 4. Get the list of trophies for each of the user's titles.
    const { trophies: titleTrophies } = await getTitleTrophies(
      authorization,
      title.npCommunicationId,
      "all",
      {
        npServiceName:
          title.trophyTitlePlatform !== "PS5" ? "trophy" : undefined
      }
    );

    // 5. Get the list of _earned_ trophies for each of the user's titles.
    const { trophies: earnedTrophies } = await getUserTrophiesEarnedForTitle(
      authorization,
      targetAccountId,
      title.npCommunicationId,
      "all",
      {
        npServiceName:
          title.trophyTitlePlatform !== "PS5" ? "trophy" : undefined
      }
    );

    // 6. Merge the two trophy lists.
    const mergedTrophies = mergeTrophyLists(titleTrophies, earnedTrophies);

    games.push({
      gameName: title.trophyTitleName,
      platform: title.trophyTitlePlatform,
      trophyTypeCounts: title.definedTrophies,
      earnedCounts: title.earnedTrophies,
      trophyList: mergedTrophies
    });
  }

  // 7. Write to a JSON file.
  fs.writeFileSync("./games.json", JSON.stringify(games));
}

const mergeTrophyLists = (
  titleTrophies: Trophy[],
  earnedTrophies: Trophy[]
) => {
  const mergedTrophies: any[] = [];

  for (const earnedTrophy of earnedTrophies) {
    const foundTitleTrophy = titleTrophies.find(
      (t) => t.trophyId === earnedTrophy.trophyId
    );

    mergedTrophies.push(
      normalizeTrophy({ ...earnedTrophy, ...foundTitleTrophy })
    );
  }

  return mergedTrophies;
};

const normalizeTrophy = (trophy: Trophy) => {
  return {
    isEarned: trophy.earned ?? false,
    earnedOn: trophy.earned ? trophy.earnedDateTime : "unearned",
    type: trophy.trophyType,
    rarity: 0,
    earnedRate: Number(trophy.trophyEarnedRate),
    trophyName: trophy.trophyName,
    groupId: trophy.trophyGroupId
  };
};

main();

and tsc index.ts turns it into this horribleness (index.js)...
"use strict";
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
    __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
            s = arguments[i];
            for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
                t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
    };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
};
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (g && (g = 0, op[0] && (_ = 0)), _) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var fs = require("fs");
var psn_api_1 = require("psn-api");
function main() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var accessCode, authorization, allAccountsSearchResults, targetAccountId, trophyTitles, games, _i, trophyTitles_1, title, titleTrophies, earnedTrophies, mergedTrophies;
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            switch (_a.label) {
                case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, (0, psn_api_1.exchangeNpssoForCode)("GqO4rje8Hx1sFqeEbzckLYND101S51LqWaXIrlMbC7TWybbZAYZygCqCSE8wx64E")];
                case 1:
                    accessCode = _a.sent();
                    return [4 /*yield*/, (0, psn_api_1.exchangeCodeForAccessToken)(accessCode)];
                case 2:
                    authorization = _a.sent();
                    return [4 /*yield*/, (0, psn_api_1.makeUniversalSearch)(authorization, "andykasen13", "SocialAllAccounts")];
                case 3:
                    allAccountsSearchResults = _a.sent();
                    targetAccountId = allAccountsSearchResults.domainResponses[0].results[0].socialMetadata
                        .accountId;
                    return [4 /*yield*/, (0, psn_api_1.getUserTitles)(authorization, targetAccountId)];
                case 4:
                    trophyTitles = (_a.sent()).trophyTitles;
                    games = [];
                    _i = 0, trophyTitles_1 = trophyTitles;
                    _a.label = 5;
                case 5:
                    if (!(_i < trophyTitles_1.length)) return [3 /*break*/, 9];
                    title = trophyTitles_1[_i];
                    return [4 /*yield*/, (0, psn_api_1.getTitleTrophies)(authorization, title.npCommunicationId, "all", {
                            npServiceName: title.trophyTitlePlatform !== "PS5" ? "trophy" : undefined
                        })];
                case 6:
                    titleTrophies = (_a.sent()).trophies;
                    return [4 /*yield*/, (0, psn_api_1.getUserTrophiesEarnedForTitle)(authorization, targetAccountId, title.npCommunicationId, "all", {
                            npServiceName: title.trophyTitlePlatform !== "PS5" ? "trophy" : undefined
                        })];
                case 7:
                    earnedTrophies = (_a.sent()).trophies;
                    mergedTrophies = mergeTrophyLists(titleTrophies, earnedTrophies);
                    games.push({
                        gameName: title.trophyTitleName,
                        platform: title.trophyTitlePlatform,
                        trophyTypeCounts: title.definedTrophies,
                        earnedCounts: title.earnedTrophies,
                        trophyList: mergedTrophies
                    });
                    _a.label = 8;
                case 8:
                    _i++;
                    return [3 /*break*/, 5];
                case 9:
                    // 7. Write to a JSON file.
                    fs.writeFileSync("./games.json", JSON.stringify(games));
                    return [2 /*return*/];
            }
        });
    });
}
var mergeTrophyLists = function (titleTrophies, earnedTrophies) {
    var mergedTrophies = [];
    var _loop_1 = function (earnedTrophy) {
        var foundTitleTrophy = titleTrophies.find(function (t) { return t.trophyId === earnedTrophy.trophyId; });
        mergedTrophies.push(normalizeTrophy(__assign(__assign({}, earnedTrophy), foundTitleTrophy)));
    };
    for (var _i = 0, earnedTrophies_1 = earnedTrophies; _i < earnedTrophies_1.length; _i++) {
        var earnedTrophy = earnedTrophies_1[_i];
        _loop_1(earnedTrophy);
    }
    return mergedTrophies;
};
var normalizeTrophy = function (trophy) {
    var _a;
    return {
        isEarned: (_a = trophy.earned) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : false,
        earnedOn: trophy.earned ? trophy.earnedDateTime : "unearned",
        type: trophy.trophyType,
        rarity: 0,
        earnedRate: Number(trophy.trophyEarnedRate),
        trophyName: trophy.trophyName,
        groupId: trophy.trophyGroupId
    };
};
main();

Everyone on the internet says to change my tsconfig.json, but I'm using ES6 (here's my code)
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target" : "ES6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "strict": true
    }
}

I'm running Windows 11, using VS Code, installed Node.js from the website and then npm install-ed typescript. Please help me out I'm losing it. What am I doing wrong that index.js isn't just using async/await normally?

Your question does not contain a question.

fair enough. i'll edit it to ask "what am I doing wrong so that the javascript file isn't just using regular async functions?"

You need to update your tsconfig.json to target at least es2017 for TypeScript to emit native async/await code. Anything less than es2017 (e.g. es2016, es2015 or es6) will transpile down to the code you're seeing.

I've tried ES2021 and ES2017. Both output the code I'm seeing.

You ran tsc index.ts. From Typescript docs: when input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

If not using tsc index.ts, what should i use instead?

Use (files)[https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files] or include properties inside tsconfig.json to tell it the entry point to compile.

How about tsc (without index.ts)?

tsc without the index.ts works beautifully. thank you all so much!!

As mentioned by others, the ES6 standard published in 2015 (also known as es2015) did not have async/await in the spec. It only had Promises. In es6, the await keyword was reserved for future use but does not specify the meaning. So if you are targeting es6 Typescript should not emit async/await code

See the comments for the full conversation, but here's what I was missing:

I needed to add "index.ts" to my tsconfig.json file, and edit the "target" to be something newer than "ES6", as such:

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target" : "ES2021",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "strict": true
    },
    "files": [
        "index.ts"
    ]
}


The console command needed to be shifted from tsc index.ts to tsc.

Thank you to @zerkms, @qrsngky, and @Sly_cardinal for the full answer!
